# Side length is half translation length ? (for right angled hexagons given by three loxodromic isometries in $\mathbb{H}^n$)

Tags: geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, geometric-group-theory

I am studying representations of the free group on $2$ generators $F_2$ into the group of isometries of the hyperbolic $n$-space $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{H}^n)$, which involves looking at the right angled hexagon given by two generators $a$ and $b$ (obtained by first drawing the axis of $a$, $b$ and $ab$, and then by drawing the common perpendicular of each couple of lines, except if they intersect). I am in a setting where I can make sure that these right-angled hexagons (RAH) make sense and can always be built (all primitive elements are sent to loxodromic isometries, and the representation is irreducible).

I am interested in a geometric property of representations that I know to be true if $n\leq 3$, namely that the distance between two vertices of a given RAH (obtained from a basis of $F_2$) that both are on the axis of a primitive element $u$ is half its translation length. For convenience, let us denote by $d_{\mathcal{H}}(u)$ the given side length, and by $l(u)$ the translation length, so that our property is $d_\mathcal{H}(u) = \frac12l(u)$.

The only proof that I know of in dimension $3$ is to write the isometries as the product of the half-turns around the common perpendiculars of the RAH, which comes down to factorizing the associated representation of $F_2$ by a representation of $W_3^2=F(p,q,r)/<p^2,q^2,r^2>$. In bigger dimensions, I know that not all representations can be factorized through $W_3^2$, so that this proof can't apply, but it still shows that there are some representations having this property.

I would like to know whether all representations have this property for arbitrary $n$, and if not, which representations have it (are the one that factor through $W_3^2$ the only ones ?). Even a counterexample would be great !

All I have managed to prove for now is that if you extend a RAH given by $a$,$b$ and $ab$ (say $\mathcal{H}$) with the one given by $a$, $b$ and $ba$ (say $\mathcal{H}'$), then $d_\mathcal{H}(a)+d_\mathcal{H'}(a) = l(a)$, so it remains to show (if it is true…) that $d_\mathcal{H}(a) = d_\mathcal{H'}(a)$. The proof is quite simple: $a$ sends the axis of $ba$ onto the axis of $ab$, so that the common perpendicular with $ab$ is the image by $a$ of the common perpendicular with $ba$.

It seems to me that this is a problem where everything can be computed (except I don't know how to compute the axis of common perpendiculars), so that it may be a classical result I am not aware of.

Comment: One quick comment: you might not be able to reduce every example down to dimension $3$, but you *can* reduce every example down to some fixed dimension. In fact you can immediately reduce it to dimension $5$, because any collection of $k$ points in $\mathbb H^n$ is contained in a totally geodesic subspace of dimension $\le k-1$. Furthermore, since the six points in question satisfy additional constraints, I suspect that you might be able to reduce down to dimension $4$.

Comment: Meanwhile, you might want to take a look at this paper of Andrew Silverio: "Half-turn linked pairs of isometries of hyperbolic 4-space",
Topology Proc. 48 (2016), 173–202.

Comment: I do not see any reason why this should hold in dimensions $\ge 4$. My suggestion is to make some computer-aided experiments (which are best done in the Lorentzian model of, say, $H^4$), choosing generators $a$ and $b$ at random. If for several randomly made choices you see that hexagonal side-lengths are half-translation lengths, then it is likely there is a general theorem. Most likely, you will get an inequality.

Comment: The claim would follow from: Suppose that $a, b, c$ are loxodromic isometries of $H^n$ satisfying $abc=1$. Then there exist elliptic isometries $f,g,h$ fixing shortest geodesics connecting respective axes of $a, b, c$, such that $a=fg, b=gh, c=hf$. Why this would be true I do not know. If $n=3$ then these elliptics are half-rotations which are known to exist.

Comment: @LeeMosher I am aware of this geometric reduction of the question, but I do not see how it can help. I think you would need that this lower dimensional space is fixed by both $a$ and $b$ for this argument to work. I think we need more than a geometric reduction because given only the RAH, one cannot say what are the translation lengths of the isometries that gave rise to this RAH.

Comment: Concerning the article you mentioned, it seems to focus on reflections with respect to codimension 2 spaces (half-turns), whereas the representations that factor through $W_3^2$ can be product of any two reflections with respect to subspaces of arbitrary dimension. In addition, I know (through computing the dimension of this set of representations) that even this more general setting only do cover the general case in dimension $2$ and $3$ (asymptotically, the dimension is $\frac34$ of the total dimension).

Comment: @MoisheKohan I also thought about making some computer experiments, however I do not have much time for the moment, so this will have to wait, and I am also not really sure about how to effectively compute common perpendiculars in upper dimensions... Anyway, thank you for your second comment, because this decomposition as a product of two elliptic isometries seems to be a broader condition than that of factoring as product of involutions. I will try to investigate this a bit more.

Comment: One more thing: I forgot to mention that elliptic isometries should act as involutions on appropriate axes of $a, b, c$. As for computing perpendiculars in the Lorentzian model, this becomes a linear algebra problem.